# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on TeX - LaTeX breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3         15
Users destroyed                                   8          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Users contacted                                  13          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           122      5,016
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0      1,314
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         74      8,591
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                4      1,744
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0     10,769
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               55     18,187
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          2
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               17        154
Questions protected                               1         48
Questions migrated                                9          6
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                5      1,052
Questions closed                                124      5,224
Question flags handled⁴                         227        830
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                  16        497
Posts locked                                      1         75
Posts deleted⁵                                  445      6,955
Posts bumped                                      0      4,369
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               12          0
Comments flagged                                  0     13,493
Comments deleted⁶                             7,984     20,085
Comment flags handled                         6,604      6,889
Answers flagged                                   8      4,529
Answer flags handled                          1,155      3,382
All comments on a post moved to chat             31          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the difference is between "suspended", "deleted" and the more ominous "destroyed" categories?

Comment: What does it mean to "*amortize* the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort"? [emphasis added]  As far as I understand the linked piece, "A theory of moderation", the design has absolutely nothing to do with "amortization" -- at least not in any of the usual senses of the word. Why don't you just write that you "*spread* the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort"?

Comment: @AlanMunn suspended means they get a time out for a bit (no question, answers, comments and their rep is set to 1 until the suspension is over). Deleted means the account is gone, but their questions, answers etc still exist but now say userxxxxx. Destroyed means the account is gone and all the content is deleted (10k+ users can still see it and it says userxxxxx). Spammers and sockpuppet accounts tend to get destroyed. Real users who want to leave get deleted.

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for the explanation!